# IE 10 loading wrong media queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, internet-explorer-10, twitter-bootstrap-3

Why are the Media Queries loading the smallest sized text only in Internet Explorer 10 on the homepage below:

http://www.jussbuss.tv/testing/kpat

The Media Queries are as follows:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:320px) {
    #masthead_home a.logoa_home {
        font-size:1.0em;
    }
    #masthead_home a.logob_home {
        font-size:0.5em;
    }

@media only screen and (min-width:480px) {
    #masthead_home a.logoa_home {
        font-size:2.0em;
    }
    #masthead_home a.logob_home {
        font-size:1.0em;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
    #masthead_home a.logoa_home {
        font-size:4.0em;
    }
    #masthead_home a.logob_home {
        font-size:2em;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1024px) {
    #masthead_home a.logoa_home {
        font-size:5.0em;
    }
    #masthead_home a.logob_home {
        font-size:3.0em;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1140px) {
    #masthead_home a.logoa_home {
        font-size:8.0em;
    }
    #masthead_home a.logob_home {
        font-size:4em;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width:1280px) {
    #masthead_home a.logoa_home {
        font-size:10.0em;
    }
    #masthead_home a.logob_home {
        font-size:5.0em;
    }
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5),
       only screen and (min-resolution:144dpi) {
    #masthead_home a.logoa_home {
        font-size:10.0em;
    }
    #masthead_home a.logob_home {
        font-size:5.0em;
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the code /media queries which set the font size

Comment: Thank you Bass, I have added the media queries. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing `}` for the first media rule. This causes the following media rules to be treated as nested, which isn't supported by IE10, and so the other media rules are being ditched, leaving you with only the first one being applied.

You should get used to use proper formatting, it's much easier to spot such errors then. Also using a proper IDE that supports syntax validation is a good idea too, that way it's pretty much impossible for such errors to slip through.

Comment: How  embarrassing!This is my first Stackoverflow post. Thank you!